# HUAWEI E173 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I have a HUAWEI E173 usb stick to access the internet.

It works normally on windows but I'd like to be able to use it on my Ubuntu system as well.

I plug it in, and after 25-20 seconds the status light turns green and blinks twice every 3 seconds, which according to the manual means that the stick is activated and waiting to connect to a network.

I see no changes in my system whatsoever, nothing gets installed, I don't get prompted for my PIN, no reaction at all.

How should I proceed in order to get it working?

Comment: Turns out all I had to do was plug the device on a USB 3 port. Then after about 30 seconds the menu from the accepted answer appeared, and after setting it up, it all worked fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once it activated, click on network applet and create new connection.

See the image below, It doesn't prompt software installation probably because the software is only for windows.

[image]

[image]

If you don't see `New Broadband Connection` , please post result of `lsusb` & `dmesg | tail` while the usb connected and activated.

Comment: Turns out all I had to do was plug it in a USB3 port and wait for 30 seconds. Thank you for your time - the image helped me a lot to get my answer.

Comment: Hello @Web-E, Can you check my problem [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/702005/cannot-connect-to-the-internet-with-huawei-3g-usb-modem) ... I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else is having this problem, I'll post what I did.

The only thing you need to do with these kinds of modems is to switch it from "Mass storage mode" to "Modem mode". To do this, you just need to add the following line to `/etc/modules`

```
usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x14ba
```

Where `0x12d1` and `0x14ba` is your vendor and product id obtained from `lsusb`

After this, restart your computer, and everything should be back to normal. You will be able to add a mobile broadband as usual.

I had this same problem, and this post got me on the right track: http://www.geekride.com/huawei-e173-on-ubuntu/

Comment: My product ID shifts around every time I reboot, so not working for me...

Answer (score 1):

The last time I used the same Huawei USB modem, I used [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12000198&postcount=2). Summarizing here for others to benefit:

From [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12000198&postcount=2):

> Enter the command in a terminal:
>
> ```
> gksudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
> ```
>
> Edit the following line from:
>
> ```
> # Huawei E173
> ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1557", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> # Huawei E173
> ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="14ba", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
> ```
>
> i.e. Change "1557" to "14ba".
>
> Save the file, exit it, remove and replug the Huawei stick again. It
>   should now be recognized and work as expected.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I went into the rules and made the change.  This is how it now reads:  # Huawei E173
ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1436", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"        I tried removing the stick and plugging it back in.  I also tried restarting the laptop.  Still no joy.

Comment: Hi. Try editing to 14ba instead of 1436.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the connection to connect to the internet. I prefer use New Mobile Broadband Connection.


This is the step to create the connection:

Open dash, search connections, and click network connections.

Choose mobile broadband, then click add

[image]

Picture of the network connections

After you click add,you can see New Mobile Broadband connection, choose continue, click on your country, click continue, and you can see a box listing some provider in your country
[image]

Click continue and then apply

After you click apply, you should give information about the modem, like username and password
[image]

Then click Save.

After that, connect your modem and you can use the modem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I did try to do this but the laptop still does not recognize the USB mobile broadband.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do with these kinds of modems is to switch it from "Mass storage mode" to "Modem mode". To do this, you just need to add the following line to `/etc/modules`

```
usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x14ba
```

Where `0x12d1` and `0x14ba` is your vendor and product id obtained from `lsusb`

After this, restart your computer, and everything should be back to normal. You will be able to add a mobile broadband as usual.

I had this same problem, and this post got me on the right track: http://www.geekride.com/huawei-e173-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

**Download Driver/MobilePartner**

Download the driver from the following link to your download folder and extract it:

http://www.umunthu.net/downloads/linux.zip

**Install Driver/MobilePartner**

Run Terminal and go to the download folder

```
cd Downloads
```

Go into the extracted folder Linux

```
cd Linux
```

Run the installation script

```
sudo bash install
```

If you get the messages "The Linux NDIS driver is installed successfully." and "Finished, press any key to exit" everything went fine.

**Reboot and test**

Reboot the system. Insert the data card and wait some seconds. After some seconds the the connection software "Movistar 3.5G" will open. Press "Connect" and you will be connected (you don't have to bother that it says connect to "Movistar Banda Ancha Movil", it will connect to the Operator of the inserted SIM card).