# How to use Huawei E173 in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, huawei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HUAWEI E173 on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179324/huawei-e173-on-ubuntu-12-04)

I have a Huawei E173 USB stick to access the internet. It works normally on windows but I need to use it on my Ubuntu system.

I plug it in, and after 25-20 seconds the status light turns green and blinks twice every 3 seconds. I see no changes in my system whatsoever, nothing gets installed, I don't get prompted for my PIN.

I tried to create a connection using edit connections.  I entered the following parameters: Turkey, Turkcell, My Plan is not listed, Internet.  Nothing happens.

I tried the `lsusb` command and got the following:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:a001 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:14ba Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

I tried the `usb-devices` command and can see the device:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=14ba Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=HUAWEI Technology
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

Based on other advice I found, I tried the following command:

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x14ba
```

Again, nothing happened.

My question is why does the "enable mobile broadband" not populate automatically in the dropdown networking menu and how can I start using the device?