# Huawei E1731 not getting detected in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: networking, usb-modem, huawei

I got a new airtel data card with Huawei E1731 firmware. My laptop is Dell Inspiron 14. When I plugged in the device into my laptop, It is not even detecting that device as an USB. I went into `/media` directory, and I found that it is empty. I have a set of installation files in my data card's USB storage which could run the configurations. I am posting this question after trying all the options mentioned in this forum like using network manager, using wvdial etc. I was not able to execute `apt-get usb-modeswitch` as I don't have any internet available for that laptop.

Regards,
Renga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your card should be detected by default as reported , see - [HUAWEI E173 on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/179324/35775)

First if you are trying the device in USB3.0 port, try switching to a USB2.0 port or vice verse and wait for 30-60 sec to check whether it detects the device(the device's lights should become stable ).

If not

1. Plugin your device, open terminal and execute `lsusb`
2. Identify the device, an example line could be

   `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:1d35 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.`
3. Carefully take a note of numbers like `****:YYYY`. The `****` defines vendor Id and `YYYY` defines product id. In above example vendor ID is `12d1` & product ID is `1d35`
4. Execute `sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x**** product=0xYYYY` (Replace with your vendor id and product id)
5. Now wait to see whether it detects and you see `New Broadband Connection` like below

   [image]
6. If everything works, execute `sudo gedit /etc/modules`
7. Add the line `usbserial vendor=0x**** product=0xYYYY` (change vendor and product id as per your output), save and reboot.

Comment: The device is not detected as an USB storage device.

Comment: That is what I said in first place, by default the device should get detected.

Comment: I did just as you said.It is detected as a mobile broadband device but not as a mass storage device.

Comment: Then create the connection, it doesn't require those installation file.

Comment: I want to install mobile partner because i cannot receive calls without mobile partner.

Comment: is it compatible with ubuntu? Please ask your query in a separate question. Comment is not a place for this discussion.

Comment: I tried multiple times these steps. Its not helping. I am seeing it as a USB Mass storage device in dmesg

Answer (score 0):

To me clicking after plugging in the device also I am not getting a link for new mobile broadband gsm connection link