# Cannot connect to the internet with Huawei 3G USB Modem

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, usb-modem

I am new to Ubuntu and to this site as well.

I tried to connect to the internet using my USB Dongle, But I am not able to connect. I have used Ubuntu a few years back, and back then my dongle automatically detected and internet connection was easy. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Here is the response to `lsusb`.

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I resolve this and get my modem working back online?

Comment: Hi There! Is it possible for you try my first method which I have mentioned here > http://askubuntu.com/a/416200/179042

Comment: @AzkerM Well hello, my problem was not with the Dongle or Ubuntu, it was getting detected, but it did not connect to the internet. At first, I thought it was an issue with the dongle not being compatible with Ubuntu. But when I tried it out after a month with another SIM card, it connected. So, my problem was with the Internet Provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a month, I found out that My problem was not with the Dongle or Ubuntu, it was getting detected, but it did not connect to the internet. At first, I thought it was an issue with the dongle not being compatible with Ubuntu. But when I tried it out after a month with another SIM card, it connected. So, my problem was with the Internet Provider.

For anyone else who is experiencing it, and are sure that the problem is not with the ISP, you might try to check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/416200/179042) answer by @[AzkerM](https://askubuntu.com/users/179042/azkerm)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here. You should try this. 
http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2012/02/3g-using-huawei-e1552e1800-hspa-modem.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.